# C# surface 2 DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am working in Visual C# -> surface -> v2.0 -> Surface Application (WPF) template in MS visual C# 2010 express.

I am trying to get the inputs on the surface table (Samsung SUR40) and parse these to a JSON array.

Each input I want to add as an item in a listbox including an item id to find these back later if the input is moving.

[I found this example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/134850-listbox-item-id/) and get an error like:

> C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\SurfaceInputs\SurfaceInputs\SurfaceWindow1.xaml.cs(209,25):
>   error CS1061: 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' does not contain a
>   definition for 'DataSource' and no extension method 'DataSource'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

The same error occurs for the DisplayMember and the ValueMember.

After the failed example I tried this piece of code which give me the same error:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Hello World");
myListBox.DataSource = list;
```

I'm a newb at C# and dont know what i'm doing wrong. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `myListBox.ItemsSource = list`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) for the docs.